# For Android App Release what is difference between Ant build apk vs Android Signed Apk

Tags: android, android-studio, ant, signed

For Android Application while generating Apk usually use signed apk, what is the use of ant Apk generation?

How to use it for android native apps, where signed apk also is non debug-gable? Then what is the use of ant apk generation?

Answer (score 0):

Build apk is able to debug from any developer also.
If you build signed apk and test that apk it will not connect with debugging.
If you use the system.out then that can be seen in Android Monitor of Android Studio but Log will not be shown.

Comment: But my question is ant build vs signed apk, As both are non debuggable.